# Coloring the rest of the tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to color in the rest of the tab area in yellow.  In this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nUBVR/3/) only the tab top and body are are in yellow.

```
  <div id="tabs">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
</ul>
 <div id="tabs-1">
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to make the blue tabs yellow (all tabs)? First of all, this looks trivial. what have you tried so far? What problem are you having? and second, please describe clearly what your desired output is.

Comment: Don't forget to select an answer once you've received one that works for you.

Answer (score 2):

Using the CSS from your fiddle:

```
body {
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
/*
 * Custom styles for the inactive tabs
 */
 .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-state-default a {
    background-color: blue;
    color: yellow;
}
/*
 * Custom styles for the active tab
 */
 .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-state-active a {
    background-color: yellow;
    color: black;
}
p, #tabs-1, #tabs-2, #tabs-3 {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

I added the IDs of your tab `<div>`s and that did the trick.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nUBVR/6/)

---

**Edit**

To take it a bit further, you could even add a class to your tab `<div>`s, then instead of adding each individual ID to the CSS, just add the class name.